# Python - Mechanize input text in form

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I'd like to input some text in the text field of a form. This is my current code. What should I do next?

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.open("xyz.com")
formcount=0
for frm in br.forms():  
if str(frm.attrs["id"])=="xyz":
break
formcount=formcount+1
br.select_form(nr=formcount)

## What should I code here to input text into the form?

response = br.submit()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
br.form['id'] = 'ss-form' # This does the input
br.submit() # This will submit the form
print br.response().read() # This will read the new page returned
```

try a `print br.response().read()`. It that is what you want, you can parse the response with Beautiful Soup. `soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())`

Comment: The br.form['id'] = 'ss-form' isn't working for input.
This is what I get -
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 3101, in find_control
    return self._find_control(name, type, kind, id, label, predicate, nr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 3185, in _find_control
    raise ControlNotFoundError("no control matching "+description)
mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'ss-form'

Comment: I'm managing to submit an empty form, but am unable to submit any text. Maybe now you get what I want to do?

Comment: That means that the form doesnt have that control. YOu first have to select the right form by `br.select_form( 'name_of_the_form' )`.

Comment: Use `for form in br.forms(): print form` to find the names of all the forms and what they contain. Then select the right form before you use the `br.form['id'] = 'abc'`

Comment: The form is unnamed. That's why I'm trying to use the id.

Also, I think that I'm selecting the form correctly since it is getting submitted properly.

Comment: If you the `for form in br.forms(): print form`, you should see entries which look like ,`<frmName1 POST ... ` You need to select that form `frmName1` by the command `br.select_form( 'frmName1' )`. Submit is equivalent to clicking the submit button. You can click it anytime you want. Doesnt mean that you selected the form correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If the form is unnamed you can use:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

That will select the first form ("the 0th one").